# Not able to run Hadoop daemons

Tags: hadoop, daemons

When I run the jps command:

I only see jps as the running java program in return.

When I run start-all.sh command, I receive errrors like:Connection to port 22 refused

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop start-all.sh script uses SSH for managing it's services. Looks like that your computer/cluster:

- has no ssh daemon installed. You can install it on Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install ssh`.
- (less likely) sshd uses non-default port. Check your sshd configuration.